# How to programmatically emulate battery in Windows workstation without battery device?

Tags: windows, battery

For testing purposes I need to force Windows to think that it has battery on workstation PC.

Is there the way to fake/mock/emulate/simulate battery state/low level/charging/discharging in Windows workstation without battery device?

Can I set battery level programmatically on Windows?

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr**: Use `Windows Driver Testing Framework (WDTF) Runtime Libraries` from Windows Driver Kit (WDK)

Long instruction:

1. Install Visual Studio with Windows Driver Kit (WDK)
2. Create virtual machine
3. Seach for `WDK Test Target Setup x64-x64_en-us.msi` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits`
4. Install `WDK Test Target Setup x64-x64_en-us.msi` on virtual machine.
5. In Visual Studio, in main menu Driver > Test > Configure Devices add virtual machine to install (WDTF) Runtime Libraries.
   [image: simulate windows battery device]
6. From virtual machine copy folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Testing\Runtimes\WDTF\RunTime` on your workstation
7. From `RunTime` folder run as administrator `RegisterWDTF.exe`

Output:

```
C:\RunTime>RegisterWDTF.exe
-Delete registry state.
-Get registry path.
-Register COM DLLs.
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\Deprecated\DeviceManagement.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\DeviceSupport\WDTFDeviceSupportAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\DrvPkgLibExt.dll".
      Not a COM DLL

   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\EDT\WDTFEDTAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\IoSpy\WDTFIoAttackAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\IoSpy\WDTFIoSpyAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\SimpleIO_D3DTest.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFAnySimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFAudioSimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFBluetoothSimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFCDROMSimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFMobileBroadbandSimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFMUTT2STRESSSimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFMUTT2TCDSimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFNetworkSimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFVolumeSimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFWebcamSimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFWirelessSimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFWPDSimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimulatedBattery\WDTFSimulatedBatterySystemAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\System\WDTFSystemAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\WDTFConcurrentIOAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\WDTFCpuUtilizationSystemAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\WDTFDriverPackageAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\WDTFDriverSetupDeviceAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\WDTFDriverSetupSystemAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\WDTFDriverVerifierSystemAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\WDTFFuzzTestAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\WDTFInterfaces\WDTFInterfaces.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\WDTFPNPAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\WDTFSUPAction.dll".
   Process "C:\WDTF.DLL".
-Update registry state.
-Install Drivers.
-Done

 WDTF Registration Successful
```

Now you can use COM object "WDTF2.WDTF" in your program language like in this VBScript example:

```
'
' Variable defenition 
'
Dim WDTF
Dim SimulatedBatterySystemSystemAction


'
' Create WDTF object
'
Set WDTF = CreateObject("WDTF2.WDTF")

'
'  Get your newly created SimulatedBatterySystem action interface
'
Set SimulatedBatterySystemSystemAction = WDTF.SystemDepot.ThisSystem.GetInterface("SimulatedBatterySystem")


'  enable the simulated battery
SimulatedBatterySystemSystemAction.EnableSimulatedBattery()

'  disable real batteries
SimulatedBatterySystemSystemAction.DisableRealBatteries()

'  set to DC power status
SimulatedBatterySystemSystemAction.SetSimulatedBatteryToDC()

'  set to 50% charge level
SimulatedBatterySystemSystemAction.SetSimulatedBatteryChargePercentage(50)

WScript.Sleep 10000 

'  set to AC power status
SimulatedBatterySystemSystemAction.SetSimulatedBatteryToAC()

'  enable real batteries
SimulatedBatterySystemSystemAction.EnableRealBatteries()

'  disable the simulated battery
SimulatedBatterySystemSystemAction.DisableSimulatedBattery()
```

Here all WDTF reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/_dtf/

Just in case, Linux Fake battery module: https://github.com/hoelzro/linux-fake-battery-module

Comment: You know what, this is what I really need. Thanks for specific answer. However, at the last part where do you run the VBScript? I tried to run it on Virtual Machine (Windows 10 OS) and it leads me to another error "ActiveX components can't create objects". Do you also experience it as well?

Comment: @MHRahman I can suggest to debug script to figure out on which exact line it fails, it can gives you ideas what to do next.

Comment: Well, the problem occured on this line `Set WDTF = CreateObject("WDTF2.WDTF")`. I still have no clue why ActiveX matters and why it can't work? At first I was thinking its just a privilege issue. But I ran the script using Admin Privilege `cmd`, and that error is still appeared `ActiveX components can't create objects`

Comment: @MHRahman I'm not expert in this area, so I think that error means that "WDTF2.WDTF" actually not registered/exists in the system.

Answer (score 1):

Oleg's answer was fairly straightforward to follow but I was unable to make it simulate a battery - the actions to disable and enable the real battery did succeed.

```
PS C:\RunTime> .\RegisterWDTF.exe
This version of WDTF is compatible with Windows Build 17763.
-Delete registry state.
-Get registry path.
-Register COM DLLs.
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\Deprecated\DeviceManagement.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\DeviceSupport\WDTFDeviceSupportAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\DrvPkgLibExt.dll".
      Not a COM DLL

   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\EDT\WDTFEDTAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\IoSpy\WDTFIoAttackAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\IoSpy\WDTFIoSpyAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\SimpleIO_D3DTest.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFAnySimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFAudioSimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFBluetoothSimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFCDROMSimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFMobileBroadbandSimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFMUTT2STRESSSimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFMUTT2TCDSimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFNetworkSimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\wdtfsensorsiosimpleioaction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFVolumeSimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFWebcamSimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFWirelessSimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimpleIO\WDTFWPDSimpleIoAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\SimulatedBattery\WDTFSimulatedBatterySystemAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\System\WDTFSystemAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\WDTFConcurrentIOAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\WDTFCpuUtilizationSystemAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\WDTFDriverPackageAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\WDTFDriverSetupDeviceAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\WDTFDriverSetupSystemAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\WDTFDriverVerifierSystemAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\WDTFFuzzTestAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\WDTFInterfaces\WDTFInterfaces.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\WDTFPNPAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\Actions\WDTFSUPAction.dll".
   Process "C:\RunTime\WDTF.DLL".
-Update registry state.
-Install Drivers.
-Done

 WDTF Registration Successful
PS C:\RunTime> cscript.exe .\fake-battery.vbs
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Loading Wex.Logger.dll from systemdata.cpp linep 922 failed.
WDTF_TARGET               : INFO  :  - GetInterface("SimulatedBatterySystem")
WDTF_TARGET               : INFO  :          Target: ORANGE
WDTF_SIMBATT              : INFO  : DisableRealBatteries()
WDTF_SIMBATT              : INFO  : EnableSimulatedBattery()
WDTF_SIMBATT              : ERROR : SimulatedBatterySystem critical error installing battbus device. HRESULT=0xE0000203
C:\RunTime\fake-battery.vbs(22, 1) WDTF.SimulatedBatterySystem.1: SimulatedBatterySystem critical error installing battbus device. HRESULT=0xE0000203
```

Unfortunately there is no information that I could find on the public Internet about these errors. Hopefully someone out there comes across this and knows what to do next!

--

edit: it appears as though Visual Studio installs various drivers in addition to the testing framework so simply copying RunTime folder is insufficient. I ended up adding my workstation as a full target using VS from another workstation. This then let me simulate the battery.

[image]

Comment: 0xe0000203 - ERROR_NO_DRIVER_SELECTED - haven't see this error. Is there chance that you have used different OS / OS versions on VM and on Workstation?

Comment: I had used Win10 1809 Enterprise 64-bit for both, but I did consider that possibility, although a remote one given that disabling / enabling the real battery worked successfully - I may also try using the workstation as a testing target in Visual Studio if it lets me.

Comment: See my edit above - there are drivers installed by VS that complement the testing framework. Once I had those drivers available on my workstation I was able to properly simulate the battery.